# Snowflake Warehouse Queued Load

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just looking at the documentation about how the load on a Warehouse is calculated:
[how query load is calculated](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-load-monitoring.html#how-query-load-is-calculated)

In this table:

```
Query       Status      Execution Time / Interval (in Seconds)  Query Load
Query 1     Running     30 / 300                                0.10
Query 2     Running     201 / 300                               0.67
Query 3     Running     15 / 300                                0.05
Query 4     Running     30 / 300                                0.10
                                                Running Load    0.92
Query 5     Queued      24 / 300                                0.08
                                                Queued Load     0.08
```

Am I correct in thinking that the "Execution Time" for the Queued Query 5 ( 24 / 30) is actually the time this query spent queuing, not executing?